# Modify code to get listview string quantity by looking for some string if it present or not

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am using this code to get the quantity of strings from list view1 and save to another list view2 for now this code will transfer all strings that are in same column but I want to transfer all strings with condition if "some string" are available in same row of that string do transfer to list view2

```
Dim items As IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of String, Integer)) = ListViewJobDetails.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).GroupBy(Function(i) i.SubItems(1).Text).Select(Function(i) Tuple.Create(i.Key, i.Count))
        For Each itm In items
            MyListView.Items.Add(itm.Item1).SubItems.Add(itm.Item2.ToString())
        Next
```

Comment: can any one guide me please ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Do you want to filter the first ListView according to some keywords and fill the second list view with it?